# What preposition should follow "jealousy"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, word-usage

My favorite online dictionary tells me that *jealousy* is followed by the preposition *of*:

> jealousy (of so.|sth.) - **die Eifersucht** (auf jmdn.|etw.)

([LEO](http://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/die%20eifersucht%20etw))

But when I checked [just-the-word](http://www.just-the-word.com/main.pl?word=jealousy&combinations=combinations&cdb=thesaurus), I noticed that *of* is used only precedent to *jealousy*.
Prepositions following the noun are *between*, *about* and *at*. Looking at the examples for *jealousy about* and *jealousy at*, it seems to me that *about* and *at* are the prepositions which are taken when referring to the reason why someone is jealous.

> ... that it was **jealousy about** her ideas.
>
> ... **jealousy at** the younger man's superior talents.

As I mentioned above, the dictionary says it is possible to say *jealousy of sth*. In my understanding, this *something* can just be the reason but not *the thing I'm jealous of*.

- (Q1) Is it *jealousy of sth* or *jealousy at sth* or *jealousy about sth* when referring to the reason why someone is jealous?
  Note: I mean is it possible to say *jealousy of the talents* or must it be *at* as in the given example?

  I don't find any reliable sources that show the use of *jealousy of sb*. Though, I know that it is correct since there are many examples for *to be jealous of*:

  > They're all jealous of me.
- (Q2) Is it common to say *jealousy of sb* when referring to the person I'm jealous of?
- Supplementary question: How do I combine in one sentence both pieces of information — the person I'm jealous of and the reason why I'm jealous?
  I could probably use a genitive as in *Peter's car*, but maybe my jealousy does not refer to the car or Peter himself but to his money or his parents' money (suppose they gave him the car as a present). How could I handle such a thing?

---

(I'm sorry for combining a couple of questions into one question but they are too related to be separated.)

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer for you, but to my ear, *jealousy of* sounds better than the other options, and perhaps *jealousy over* also deserves a spot in the running. See a google ngram search of [jealousy (of|about|at|over)](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jealousy+at%2Cjealousy+over%2Cjealousy+about%2C+jealousy+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) and just [jealousy (about|at|over)](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jealousy+at%2Cjealousy+over%2Cjealousy+about&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for perspective.

Comment: Also, *jealousy for*, which is the second or third most popular on Ngrams.

Comment: jealous of him good looking, jealous about his good looks.

Comment: Your entire question would make sense that f you replace the noun 'jealousy' with the adjective 'jealous'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1: Is it *jealousy of sth* or *jealousy at sth* or *jealousy about sth* when referring to the reason why someone is jealous?**

I would think you would use the same prepositions for *jealousy* as for *jealous*.

> Paul was jealous of Bill. Paul expressed jealousy of Bill.
>
> Paul was jealous for/over his wife. Paul expressed jealousy for/over his wife.
>
> Paul was jealous for/over Bill's car. Paul expressed jealous for/over Bill's car.

<sub>Somebody correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe you can use either *for* or *over* with jealous in either of the latter two senses it holds above.</sub>

I have never heard that you could be jealous *at* something or *about* something, but if the usages are valid, I would expect that you could use them in the same with *jealousy*.

---

**Q2: Is it common to say *jealousy of sb* when referring to the person of whom I'm jealous?**

*Jealousy of/for/over/at/about something* is awkward and in my experience little-used. It is more common to say, "I am jealous of him," as in the example first sentences above.

Comment: “Paul was jealous for his wife” sounds utterly bizarre to me. I cannot think of any context where _for_ is a possible preposition to use to indicate the object of one’s jealousy in my English. It may be a regionalism. In all your examples, _of_ is the only preposition I would use; in the third one, possibly also _at_, but primarily _of_.

Comment: "Jealous for" could be used if someone is jealous on behalf of someone else. Paul's wife's colleague won an award that he thinks should or could have gone to her. 

It would also be used in the question "What are you so jealous for?", as in " 'why', or 'for what reason' are you so jealous?".

Answer (score 1):

A search of the COCA [gives](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=15700253) the most common prepositions following *jealousy* as: *of, in, over,* and *for.* If you sort by relevance, the most common are: *among, toward, over, between,* and *of.*

Your could say, *I'm jealous of Mia over her beautiful hair/for being able to do a backflip.*

Comment: Yes, in other words, it depends on what you want to say. Here's an example for "jealousy over": _He does not sleep from jealousy over his young, beautiful wife._ It suggests that he wants to own her and is afraid that she might have affairs with other men.

Answer (score 0):

One way of putting that would be to avoid prepositions altogether: *I became jealous on knowing Peter's parents bought him a posh car.*

Comment: 'on' is not a preposition?

Comment: I do not think this 'on' *attaches* to 'jealous'. Or you may have *I became jealous when I knew Peter's parents bought him a posh car.*

Comment: *On discovering* would make it a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

A selection of the quotations from the OED entry on **jealous**:

> (1828) The Chief is young, and jealous **of** his rank.
>
> (1838) Several of the leading persons in the state were jealous **of** his glory.
>
> (1853) God is contemplated as jealous **over** his people.
>
> (1888) The people, jealous **of** their hardly-won liberties.
>
> (1888) Mrs. Fausset...had been jealous of the new-comer, and resentful **of** her intrusion from the outset.
>
> (1897) The Church was, as early as 1254, becoming jealous **of** the civil law.

It is thus somewhat clear that, generally, the most appropriate preposition is **of**.

Comment: The question asks about the noun *jealousy,* not about the adjective *jealous.*

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what's being discussed here is "envy" rather than jealousy. Envy is a DESIRE-based emotion. You envy someone who is richer or smarter than you, and desire to be equally rich or smart.  Jealously, in contrast, is a FEAR-based emotion. You fear that a competitor threatens to replace you as a friend or lover. You fear losing something precious to you.  Thus you are envious OF your neighbor or OF your neighbor's flashier car. But if you catch your neighbor eyeing or sneaking around with your spouse, you are jealous --- you fear that your spouse will leave you for your neighbor. So, are you jealous OF your neighbor's interest in your spouse? To what or whom is your jealously directed? to the neighbor? to your spouse? to the threat to your relationship? I think that the English language is unclear on these questions.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm .... what preposition should follow "anger"?

- He has strong anger **about** health care inequality.
- He is expressing his anger **against** the perpetrators of inequality.
- Her anger **for** not having healthcare is eating her up.
- Her anger **at** her brother is the result of his not supporting her.
- Their **anger** towards the rich is exhibited by their refusal to file taxes.

Replace the word "anger" with "jealousy", "hate", "feelings", etc.

The preposition depends on the context.

What you are probably facing is confusion between

- the pairing of verbs with prepositions
- ascribing the appropriate preposition to the target context of a preceding noun or phrase.

You would ask the question "what preposition comes after xxx", when xxx is a verb.

- attend to
- conscious of
- account for
- believe in

https://www.keepandshare.com/doc/59788/prepositions-verbs-english-preposition-pairs.

Comment: I understand. In principle, you're right. But let's take the examples of @zpletan. Every sentence begins with *Paul expressed jealousy* and this is followed by the object only. Though, the preposition (or namely post-position) changes dependent on what the object is (the 'target' or the 'reason'). And that's what the question is about. Maybe this is not clear enough?

Comment: Not every emotion has the same kind of ... target. Some don't really have any, although *emotion* might not be the best word for those. But jealousy in particular is a desire to have, own or possess something, or to believe one had it then feel aggrieved at its loss; but it's the inherent meaning of the word that it's of/over the thing that is desired.

Answer (score -1):

***Jealous***

Examples:

> I was jealous of her nice drawing.
>
> She was jealous about her having a YouTube channel.
>
> They were jealous about us having more points than them.

All of them have the same meaning.

Comment: The question was about the noun *jealousy.*

Comment: @sumelic you might well say the same to all but one of the answers.